# Order of coef_ and estimators_ elements in scikit-learn classifiers

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In `scikit-learn`, classifiers such as [LinearSVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC) and [MultinomialNB](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html) expose the `coef_` object. This allows to inspect the weights of the model for each label, for example `coef_[0]`, `coef_[1]` etc. A full code example is shown in the [20_newsgroups documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html) in the `show_top10` method.

In case of using a [OneVsRestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier) and a pipeline, I wrote code to get the weights of a wrapped model for a three class classification:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([  
    ('scaler', MaxAbsScaler()),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True, class_weight='balanced')))])
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

pipeline.named_steps['clf'].estimators_[0].coef_.toarray()[0]
pipeline.named_steps['clf'].estimators_[1].coef_.toarray()[0]
pipeline.named_steps['clf'].estimators_[2].coef_.toarray()[0]
```

But how is the order of the elements in `coef_` (for LinearSVC) and `estimators_` (for SVC wrapped in a OneVsRestClassifier) defined?

In general, how do I reliably obtain which class `i` the `estimators_[i]` model belongs to?